# Vote is not count

Tags: python

The simple program that tallies the votes of a four-candidate election.
Votes arrive one at a time, where a vote four Candidate is denoted by the number,
At last print the winner on the screen.

there is my code

```
candList = [0, 0, 0, 0]

while True:
    print '1 for First Candidate'
    print '2 for Second Candidate'
    print '3 for Third Candidate'
    print '4 for Fourth Candidate'
    print '5 for Exit Poll'

    cid = input('Enter Candidate Number to Vote: ')

    if cid == 5:
        break

    candList[cid - 1]

vote = max(candList)
candidate = candList.index(vote) + 1
print 'Winner is  Candidate', candidate, 'with', vote, 'Votes'
```

But the problem vote is not count..
I am give 1 candidate 3 votes but finally print

```
Result is : Winner is  Candidate 1 with 0 Votes
```

Comment: `eval(raw_input())`? Are you serious?

Comment: What are you expecting `list[id - 1]` to do, exactly?! Did you mean `list[id] -= 1`? And **don't call your own list `list`**.

Comment: use `input` instead of `raw_input`, and no `eval`

Comment: @Morb, no, this is Python2, so definitely don't use `input()` - it's equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`!

Comment: Also worth noting that finding the max number of votes and then finding the index of that number is not a reliable way to find the winner. What happens if all candidates tie? What happens in general if they tie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never assign a value to `list[cid - 1]`. You should change that line into the following:

```
list[cid - 1] += 1
```

Also, I would recommend you do not use `list` as the name for your list.

Answer (score 4):

There are number of problems in your code.

First of all, `id` is a builtin function, do not use `id` as a variable name. The same goes for `list` Second, line 15 (`list[id-1]`) obviously does nothing . Third, you should not use `eval` for converting strings into integers, use `int` instead.

This code should do the work, but it still have some caveats: user can input 15 or not a number and the program will be terminated, also it doesn't handle a situation when two candidates get the same amount of votes

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 0]

while True:
    print '1 for First Candidate'
    print '2 for Second Candidate'
    print '3 for Third Candidate'
    print '4 for Fourth Candidate'
    print '5 for Exit Poll'

    cid = int(input('Enter Candidate Number to Vote: '))

    if cid == 5:
        break

    lst[cid - 1] += 1

vote = max(lst)
candidate = lst.index(vote) + 1
print 'Winner is  Candidate', candidate, 'with', vote, 'Votes'
```

Comment: "id" and "list" are mere names in Python and not reserved in any way, it's perfectly legal to use these names as you see fit. To put this as the first item in the list of problems is misleading. They are only cosmetical problems.

Comment: @skyking I do not agree with you on this. Shadowing `list` and other built-in functions is a source of confusion and a major problem from my point of view.

Comment: People are always going to disagree on cosmetical questions, there is simply not a hard way to decide who is right and who is wrong. The other problems in the code is code that throws exception and does not do what's intended.

Comment: @skyking: the problem is not that you cannot *use* these values. They are indeed not reserved, but by assigning them you override the previous meaning and so if later someone calls `list(range(42))` it will fail to work.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem While I do agree that one should not use these identifiers, it is still a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Check this You are not changing the respective persons count Change the code

```
list = [0, 0, 0, 0]

while True:
    print '1 for First Candidate'
    print '2 for Second Candidate'
    print '3 for Third Candidate'
    print '4 for Fourth Candidate'
    print '5 for Exit Poll'

    id = int(raw_input('Enter Candidate Number to Vote: '))

    if id == 5:
        break
#Change Here add the count
    list[id - 1] = list[id-1]+1

vote = max(list)
candidate = list.index(vote) + 1
print 'Winner is  Candidate', candidate, 'with', vote, 'Votes'
```